# Pygame window doesn't close after clicking red cross

Tags: python, pygame

I'm new to pygame. I have written the following code, but the generated window doesn't allow me to close it.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))


running = True
while running:
    for event  in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem, the code works fine for me. Anyway, call `pygame.quit()` after the application loop, at the end of the script.

Comment: This is likely because you're running your code in IDLE. Since IDLE doesn't end the python process after execution stops, you need to call pygame.quit() to close the window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looping and the game running are two different things. If you want to close the game after the loop ends, you should do so with `pygame.quit()`. Importing `sys` and adding `sys.exit()` as afterwards lets you exit the Python script altogether. Depending on which IDE you use, this may not happen automatically.

```
import pygame
import sys
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))


running = True
while running:
    for event  in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```